Why is it spelled "dummy" and not "dumby?"
If dummy is derived from dumb, why doesn't it have the b?

Surely the question is why does dumb still keep its silent b.

For the same reason its "crummy" and not "crumby"

Seems to be a Q about spelling? On topic? Maybe should be a Q about etymology of "dummy"? (The one answer, so far, would still fit.)

@NoName, I've seen "crumby" in print. ISTR, you can find it in The Catcher in the Rye by J. D. Salinger. In one of the early chapters, the protagonist complains about his roommate, Ackley, leaving his crumby toenail clippings on the floor.

Dumby did exist but is now obsolete:

(rare) Alternative form of dummy (“stupid person”)
(card games) Archaic form of dummy (“hand shown to be played from by another player”). (Wiktionary)

OED gives this example from 1860

He who draws the lowest card takes Dumby as his partner.
Bohn's Hand-book Games iv. 178

It's most probably the drop of /b/ in the pronunciation of dumb (/dʌm/) that made dummy a more justifiable descendant.

/mb/ was reduced to /m/ during the Middle English period:

In later Middle English, the final cluster /mb/ was reduced to just /m/ (the plum-plumb merger). This affects words such as lamb and plumb, as well as derived forms with suffixes, such as lambs, lambing, plumbed, plumber. (Wikipedia)

EDIT: I think the excellent link provided by @livresque, deserves to be inserted here. Gerard Nolst Trenité's The Chaos (1922) is "a classic English poem containing about 800 of the worst irregularities in English spelling and pronunciation". Here is the stanza that concerns our topic:

Pious, impious, limb, climb, glumly,
Worsted, worsted, crumbly [ˈkrʌmblɪ], dumbly [dʌmlɪ],
Conquer, conquest, vase, phase, fan,
Wan, sedan and artisan.


It's interesting that even Green's Dictionary of Slang mentions dumby as a variant with the latest example dating from 1849:


(also dumbie, dumby) a dumb (i.e. mute) person.


G. Colman Yngr ‘Low Ambition’ Poetical Vagaries 12: Though he had’nt been too hoarse to speak, He was too ugly, even, for a dumby. (1812)
Bell’s Life in Sydney 17 Mar. 3/3: The two of the force reinforced by a night watchman, ran as hard as two corpses trussed in blue and a dumby could. (1849)



I  was surprised not to find dumbo (with 'b' pronounced) in either M-W or Cambridge.

Almost mentioned it in my answer but opted to omit it in the end. Etymonline does have an entry for dumbo. OED and Collins do too.

"/mb/ was reduced to /b/ during the Middle English period:" -- reduced to /m/, you mean.

I have corrected that , @GlennWillen , nice catch.

Obligatory link to The Chaos https://ncf.idallen.com/english.html

@GlennWillen Very right. Thanks for pointing out the typo. Thanks Prem.

There's a nuance to what Wikipedia claims. It's true of inflectional suffixes and of some suffixes beginning with a consonant (dumbly, numbness), but some suffixes cause the previously silent final consonant to sound (crumble, bombard, condemnation, solemnity, columnist, autumnal). (I know that the OP's example involved silent b, not n, but the principle is the same and -mn words give more examples.)
